# Syntax Highlight English Language

Tags: language-agnostic, syntax-highlighting

Are there any plugins or C libraries that syntax highlight the english Language?

Considering parsing the entire English language isn't straight forward, simply syntax highlighting of nouns, verbs, pronouns, prepositions, etc. would be nice.

Comment: Well i searched around and found these :<br>
https://github.com/danieldk/citar<br>
http://www.markwatson.com/opensource/<br>
http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/claws/<br>
Hope they are helpful!